# Angular1 perfect scrollbar - doesn't propagate back to the parent page when it reaches the end of container on touch devices

Tags: angularjs, perfect-scrollbar

I've got a sidebar that breaks to full width on mobile and it won't allow me to scroll further when I get there. The JQuery version has the swipePropagation option but the angular version seems to not allow scrolling at all when the content is less than the container. Does anyone have a solution to this?